# Django CharField unique=True seems not working while unique=True is set

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using Django 3.0.2 and sqlite3 DB.

I set following simple models:

```
from django.db import models


class Description(models.Model):
    IDENTIFIER_LENGTH = 30
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=IDENTIFIER_LENGTH, blank=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
```

Strangely, the `unique=True` seems not working. Following code run in shell mode

```
from testunique.models import Description
object = Description('first-object')
object.save()
object.save()
```

doesn't raise any error. For the record, here is the SQL code of the migrations:

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model Description
--
CREATE TABLE "testunique_description" ("identifier" varchar(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
COMMIT;
```

What is wrong here? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Your second `object.save()` is an `UPDATE` query. Django remembers that it has saved the field since it is a primary key.

Comment: Furthermore since this is a primary key, it will always work with update.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks Willem for your quick response. That means that I would have to write separate code to check that the "object" is already existing in the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django considers records with a set *primary key* as records already in the database. Therefore it will *not* perform a `INSERT …` query, but an `UPDATE …`. It is sometimes used as a trick to set the primary key in Django to `None` to make a copy of a given record (since then Django will make another `INSERT …` query).

You can force insertion with:

```
Description.objects.create(name='first-object')
Description.objects.create(name='first-object')  # raises an error
```

or you can work with `force_insert=True`:

```
Description(name='first-object').save(force_insert=True)
Description(name='first-object').save(force_insert=True)  # raises an error
```